# Inequality of fourier transform for $L^2$ functions

Tags: inner-products, fourier-transform, correlation

Suppose $f,g$ are $L^2$ functions over $\mathbb R$ such that $\|f\|^2\ge \|g\|^2$ and for any $y\in \mathbb R$,
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \overline{g(x-y)} dx = 0.$$
If $F,G$ are their respective Fourier transform, is it true that
$$|F(z)|\ge |G(z)| \quad \forall z?$$

---

This is the continuous version of [majorization of polynomials over the unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404691/majorization-of-polynomials-over-the-unit-circle). I thought it may give some insight to put it in another perspective, since I can't seem to be able to prove any of them.

Comment: It looks strange. We have $\|g\|^2=r^2\|f\|^2,$ for $0<r<1.$ If your conclusion was true it would imply $|G(z)|=r|F(z)|$ for any $z.$ Do you think it is possible ? Do you have any example ?

Comment: I actually proved this is wrong. It's fairly easy too

Comment: That's what I thought. $F(z)$ and $G(z)$ may have disjoint supports.

Comment: yep, they must, so it's easy to come up with a counter example